# EOL not showing up in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application which writes this :

```
word_meaning = 'line 1' + os.EOL +'line 2';
```

and in the html file, I render this by doing:

```
<p> <%= todo.word_meaning %> </p>
```

The output in HTML is showing up as line 1  line 2. The EOL is not showing up on the html file. Instead of EOL, I tried '\n' and '\n\r'. Nothing seems to work..please help!

Comment: Are you trying to print a new line, or actually print the string `line 1\nline 2`?

Comment: I am trying to print a new line on my web page

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are trying to have os line endings on an html template. HTML does not recognize line endings. What you need to add instead of a `os.EOL` is a `<br />` as such:

`word_meaning = 'line 1' + '<br />' +'line 2';`

Although I'm sure that would cause an aneurism to many a web designer, but it will work assuming your styles aren't messing with `<br />` :)